# Proof of non-computability of subset of a countably infinite set

Tags: computational-complexity, computational-algebra

In my statistical programming work, I have run into a computational problem that I am unfamiliar with.  Although my problem is a bit more detailed, it can be boiled down to the following.  Suppose we have an arbitrary black-box function $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \{ 0,1 \}$ and we want to find the [preimage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)):

$$f[1] = \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} | f(x) = 1 \}.$$

Suppose that we restrict attention to functions which give a preimage that is a finite union of connected intervals (so that the bounds of each interval can be written out).  By "find the preimage" here, I have in mind computing an output that would tell the user the bounds of each of the intervals --- for example:

```
FIND_PREIMAGE(f)

      Preimage of the function f

-Inf..-806, -720..-43, 12..14, 85..9015, 60478..101056
```

Now, suppose we have programmed the function $f$ and so for any input $x$ we can compute $f(x)$ in a finite number of operations.  Intuitively, it seems to me that even with such a function available, it is impossible to find an algorithm that could compute the above output (for an arbitrary function of this kind) in a finite number of operations.  Unless I am mistaken, the set of all functions of this kind is cardinally equivalent to the real numbers, so it seems to me that computing the image set for any function would require an infinite number of operations.

Unfortunately, all this is just my intuition, and this is a problem that is well outside my own field.  I do not know if this problem has a name  in the computation literature, or if there is an existing  proof that this is impossible to compute.  This seems like a problem that is sufficiently simple and fundamental that it is probably well-known.

---

**My Question:** Does the above computational problem (or something similar) have a name/literature?  Is there an existing proof of that this cannot be computed in a finite number of operations?

Comment: This is called [pre-image or inverse image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image) $f^{-1}[1]$, and it is unclear what "compute this set in a finite number of operations" means. It is trivially [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_set) in the usual sense: take any number, evaluate $f$ on it, and return "yes" if the value is $1$, otherwise "no".

Comment: (I removed the previous comment because it has some mistake.) As @Conifold points out, you incorrectly call an inverse image an image. Your guess is correct if you asked the question for images: the halting set $K$ is an image of a computable function, but itself is not computable.

Comment: What do you mean by "compute this set"? For any subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ we can find $f$ such that $f^{-1}[1]=A$. In particular any infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is realizable. Can you "compute" an infinite set in finite steps? Or do you actually want some symbolic description of $f^{-1}[1]$? In terms of what? Isn't $f^{-1}[1]$ already a solution?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback everyone --- I have updated my question to specify what I mean by "computing the set".  What I have in mind is being able to compute and write out the bounds of each of the intervals that make up the set.

Answer (score 1):

> Unless I am mistaken, the set of all functions of this kind is cardinally equivalent to the real numbers, so it seems to me that computing the image set for any function would require an infinite number of operations.

In fact, the set of all such functions *is* countable: note that every function is given by the finitely many values $i$ for which $f(i) = 1$, and we could associate to each such function $f$ the number
$$
q(f) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb Z : f(i) = 1} 2^i,
$$
and this will be a rational number, because there are only finitely many binary digits after the "decimal" point.

However, your intuition that this is not computable is correct. Because the input function is treated as a black box, we do not even need the machinery of computability (the halting problem, etc.) here. The proof is simpler. Suppose that you *could* compute the preimage in finitely many operations for each $f$, and let's denote the algorithm by the letter $A$. Then consider the function $f_0$ with $f_0(0) = 1$, while $f_0(n) = 0$ for all $n \neq 0$. Now $A(f_0)$ only calls the function $f_0$ finitely many times, because it gets the result in finitely many operations. So suppose it calls $f_0(n_1), f_0(n_2), \cdots, f_0(n_k)$. Write $m = \max(n_1, \ldots, n_k)$. Then let the function $f$ be given as follows: we define $f(0) = f(m+1) = 1$, and $f(n) = 0$ if $n \notin \{0, m+1\}$. Then in the computation of $A(f)$, the algorithm must do the exact same thing as it did to $A(f_0)$, because for the purposes of the computation, $f, f_0$ are indistinguishable. Thus the output for both will be the same, but $f \neq f_0$. Thus such an $A$ cannot exist.

Comment: It is not necessarily the case that the preimage is a finite set --- I only specify that it is composed of a finite number of intervals (but an interval may be unbounded).  In the example I give in the question, the lowest interval is unbounded from below, so the preimage is infinite.

Comment: I am satisfied that your proof proves the non-computability I was looking for (+1).  Is there a name in the field of computation for the type of problem I am presenting here?

Comment: @Ben, right, I didn't notice; it doesn't matter, though, you could change the sum to be over the bounds of the intervals, and then replace the 2 either by $3^i$ or $2 \times 3^i$ depending on whether it is a left or a right bound. It's just a matter of encoding slightly more information.